# "class" is ambiguous for type lookup in this context in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, cocoapods

I'm using pods in my project. When using [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa) and [permission](https://github.com/delba/Permission) libraries, I got error " "Permission" is ambiguous for type lookup in this context".

When I click on Permission in my method it's actually going to "Permission" Which is defined in realm.[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uaYt.png).

But actually it should read the permission class from "Permission" Module. [Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45GSg.png)

Now I came to know that it's name conflict. Two modules are using same name. I tried by referring (Modulename.classname) like Permission.permission.Still it's giving same error. So how to refer to class Which is in permission module.

Thanks..

Comment: Dont import Realm as a whole module.

Comment: @Sulthan Im importing like this "import RealmSwift". I didn't understand what do u mean by whole module ?

Comment: Exactly that. You cannot import `RealmSwift` otherwise you will also import `Permission` and that will be conflicting with the module `Permission`. If you need both modules (`RealmSwift` and `Permission`) in one file, don't `import` either of them and use the fully qualified names for both.

Comment: @Sulthan Can u give me one example.  I need to use both in single file. I removed both import statements. Now I have to call Modulename.classname which Imnot able to do